# How to add GDAL to existing Python installation?

Tags: python, gdal

I would like to download and install GDAL for Python version 2.6 [MCS v.1500 32 bit(Intel)] on win32 that supports reading FileGDB's with Python.  But I am not sure how to go about this.

I found one exe at [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) but it was not built with the FileGDB included.  I also tried the OSGeo4w Installer but it currently installs its own 2.7 version of Python rather than allowing the GDAL to be installed with the existing version of Python.

I must work with the 2.6 version installed on our systems.  Can anyone be of assistance in locating a GDAL build that supports FileGDB's, can be installed with my existing Python version 2.6 and provide detailed instructions?

Answer (score 4):

I was in the same situation as you it sounds like - I needed to install it to use the Python 2.6.5 install with ArcGIS. Here is how I did it.

**ESRI FGDB API install**

1. Download and unzip the FGDB API from Esri at: http://resources.arcgis.com/content/geodatabases/10.0/file-gdb-api. Yes, you have to login to download it. Ver 1.1 at time of this writing, get the VS2010 version.
2. Unzip the FGDB API to a directory, I did mine to C:\Program Files\ESRI FileGDB API. Add the path to the bin directory (mine is C:\Program Files\ESRI FileGDB API\bin) to your `PATH` environmental variable. FileGDBAPI.dll has to be in your `PATH`.

**GDAL 1.9 install**

1. Download Win32 GDAL 1.9/Mapserver binary package from http://vbkto.dyndns.org/sdk/.
2. Install the GDAL build by unzipping it to somewhere like C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL.
3. Setup and config of GDAL and plugins:

   - Path to /bin needs to be in PATH env. variable (C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\bin)
     Also, so does: C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\bin\gdal\apps and C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\bin\gdal\python
   - Copy ogr_FileGDB.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\bin\gdal\plugins-external to C:\Program Files\GDAL\bin\gdal\plugins
   - Create new env. variable named GDAL_DRIVER_PATH with value of C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\bin\gdal\plugins. This will make all of your plugin dlls available as drivers to GDAL.
4. Test by running `ogrinfo --formats`

**Python 2.6.5 support**

Got this error when trying to import gdal:

```
C:\>cd "Program Files (x86)\GDAL\bin\gdal\python"

C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\bin\gdal\python>python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from osgeo import gdal
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\bin\gdal\plugins\
gdal_GEOR.dll
126: The specified module could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\bin\gdal\plugins\
gdal_GEOR.dll
126: The specified module could not be found.
```

This is the driver for Oracle GeoRaster, which I don't need, so I moved gdal_GEOR.dll from \plugins to \plugins-optional.

Comment: @user1214192 - Yes, I believe you would want the VS2008 version.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can't use OsGeo4w, you need to set things up yourself. It's sometimes a non-trivial process but the main idea will be 1) install GDAL, 2) fix your PATH variables, and 3) install Python bindings. I am unable to verify on my own system at the moment, but [this](https://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/) seems a good walk-through of that process. Before you get started, make sure you completely wipe out any previous GDAL installations, that will save you a lot of headache.

Keep in mind, OGR supports File Geodatabases as of 1.9.0, so you will need to grab GDAL/OGR binaries that are at least that version (or higher).

GDAL Binaries can be [found here](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php), and you can get Python bindings [off PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/).

Comment: I found this to be a useful walk-through, it worked for me on windows 7. http://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/installing-gdal-and-ogr-for-python-on-windows/