# Why does OGR driver.Open() for File Geodatabase give AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute Open?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, gdal, ogr, file-geodatabase

There are a number of existing Questions that hint at a possible Answer to this Question, but none seem to be providing me with the solution to my problem:

- [How to access feature classes in file geodatabases with Python and GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32762/how-to-access-feature-classes-in-file-geodatabases-with-python-and-gdal)
- [How to add GDAL to existing Python installation?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39340/how-to-add-gdal-to-existing-python-installation)
- [Gdal Python Bindings and File Geodatabase API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64864/gdal-python-bindings-and-file-geodatabase-api)

To get **GDAL/OGR 1.10** working on a **Windows 7 SP1 (64bit)** laptop with **Python 2.7.3** from **ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop** I did the following steps:

1. Installed ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop which installed Python 2.7.3 - there are no other versions of Python present
2. Downloaded and installed `gdal-110-1600-x64-core.msi` (compiled 2/6/2014 6:11 AM) from http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1600-x64-gdal-mapserver
3. Downloaded and installed `gdal-110-1600-x64-filegdb.msi` (compiled 2/6/2014 6:17 AM) from http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1600-x64-gdal-mapserver.  As expected this placed an `ogr_FileGDB.dll` in C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins.
4. Added a new system environment variable called `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` and set it to C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins, and I appended (using ';') the same folder onto the end of my `Path` variable.  This was from advice offered in one of the Questions cited above.
5. Downloaded and installed `GDAL-1.10.1.win32-py2.7.exe` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal

This enabled me to run some Python scripts from IDLE like the one below to count the number of features in a shapefile.

```
import os
from osgeo import ogr

daShapefile = r"C:\temp\test.shp"

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

dataSource = driver.Open(daShapefile, 0) # 0 means read-only. 1 means writeable.

# Check to see if shapefile is found.
if dataSource is None:
    print 'Could not open %s' % (daShapefile)
else:
    print 'Opened %s' % (daShapefile)
    layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
    featureCount = layer.GetFeatureCount()
    print "Number of features in %s: %d" % (os.path.basename(daShapefile),featureCount)
```

However, when I tried to run the code below:

```
import os
from osgeo import ogr

daFileGeodatabaseFC = r"C:\temp\test.gdb\testFC"
daFileGeodatabase = r"C:\temp\test.gdb"
featClass = "testFC"

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('FileGDB')

dataSource = driver.Open(daFileGeodatabase, 0) # 0 means read-only. 1 means writeable.

# Check to see if feature class is found.
if dataSource is None:
    print 'Could not open %s' % (daFileGeodatabase)
else:
    print 'Opened %s' % (daFileGeodatabase)
    layer = dataSource.GetLayer(featClass)
    featureCount = layer.GetFeatureCount()
    print "Number of features in %s: %d" % (os.path.basename(daFileGeodatabaseFC),featureCount)
```

I got an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\temp\GetFileGDBFeatureCount.py", line 17, in 
>       dataSource = driver.Open(daFileGeodatabase, 0) # 0 means read-only. 1 means writeable. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no
>   attribute 'Open'

After some more reading I decided to use `ogrinfo --formats` in a DOS window to see if FileGDB was recognized and it is!

[image]

**Am I missing a step or two that would complete enabling OGR FileGDB support for my GDAL/Python/ArcGIS configuration?**

I do not class myself as a developer so compiling a new version of GDAL, or starting from scratch and installing OSGeo4W instead are options I would prefer to avoid, if at all possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are a few things I noticed, your Python 2.7.3, installed with ArcGIS, is 32 bit while the filegdb plugin is 64 bit. You may need a 64 bit Python to match the filegdb driver. Also, you installed two versions of GDAL 32 bit & 64 bit, this might be ok. When you import osgeo, which version are you importing, 32 or 64?  Your GDAL_DRIVER_PATH points to the 64 bit install, looks good.

Comment: +1 I suspect that you are right and am now trying to standardize these parts of my configuration on 32bit to match the Python installed with ArcGIS but if I get no further then I will install Background Geoprocessing to to try and standardize on 64bit instead.